# Convert columns of number into percentages

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 4 columns. The 4th column is sum of values of 3 columns.
It is like this.

```
A  B  C  D
4  3  3  10
```

I want to convert above expression into this.

```
E   F   G   H
40% 30% 30% 100%
```

How can I do this in python ?

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by columns? Is it same as a two dimensional array (matrix)

Comment: By columns, I mean the Columns A,B,C,D and want another columns in the format of E,F,G,H. And they all are of same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy arrays for this operation, let’s consider that all the columns are represented by vectors then first 3 columns are represented by 3 vectors.

```
A = numpy.array([4])
B = numpy.array([3])
C = numpy.array([3])
```

Then you can add them as normal vectors (in your case columns)

```
D = A + B + C
```

All the numerical values will be work as you expected but according to my knowledge problem is letters those can’t be added like you mentioned. Because if we consider

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
```

Then the answer would be 10 or J not D, same goes for the second set.